# Dataflow: is it possible to run parts of the pipeline synchronously and other parts asynchronously?

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

I am setting up simple Dataflow pipeline that looks something like this:

```
Pipeline p = Pipeline.create(options);
p.apply(TextIO.Read.from("source.csv"))
.apply(ParDo.of(new TransformEachLine()))
.apply(ParDo.of(new ProcessEachTransform()));
p.run();
```

How can I make each iteration of `TransformEachLine` wait while each iteration of `ProcessEachTransform` completes ALL elements that were produced by the corresponding `TransformEachLine` iteration? Also, how can I make each iteration of `TransformEachLine` execute sequentially (as appears in the source ".csv" file)

Basically, it is important for me to scale horizontally and randomize the `ProcessEachTransform`, but NOT the previous two `ParDo`s at the same time.

Right now, hypothetical output from this pipeline would looks something like this:

```
Line B
   Processed item 2
   Processed item 1
   Processed item 3
Line A
   Processed Item 3
   Processed Item 1
   Processed Item 2
Line C
   Processed Item 1
   Processed Item 3
   Processed Item 2
```

How can I align "Line XX" sequentially, but keep "Processed Item XX" randomized and paralellized within each "Line XX"? Does it mean that I have to execute parts of the code locally and send other parts to Dataflow for for parallel processing?

Comment: Can you tell more about your use case: how many "Lines" are there and how many Items per line? Why do you need to process them sequentially? Does it matter in what order you process them (same as order in the .csv file?), or only that two Lines don't get processed at the same time?

Comment: Because these are financial transactions. Suppose (1) A pays B and then (2) B pays C (historical data, processed in batch mode). If (2) is processed before (1), you may have insufficient funds, even though in real life it wasn't the case due to (1). So, it's important to execute (1) and (2) in sequence. At the same time, suppose each transaction involves a million operations (or multiples of). It would be nice to process (1) and (2) in consequence, but to distribute each sub-operation among a magnitude of worker nodes, so they are processed quickly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you actually need to process things exactly in the order specified in the input file.

That's not something that you can directly express in the Beam API: processing of elements of a PCollection is always parallel and unordered - you'll need to run each transaction as a single pipeline in sequence (though if the number of transactions is low - at most in the hundreds - you can express the sequencing in the structure of the pipeline itself, something like 1 transform per transaction and some wiring to make the transforms execute in sequence - let me know if you'd like to know about this and I'll edit my answer).

Please note that the Beam model also makes no guarantees as to *how many times* an element will be processed (e.g. a runner can process an element several times in case of failure retries, or for redundancy), so you'll need to make the processing of items in one transaction idempotent as well.

Comment: Well, the number of transactions is very large, definitely not in hundreds, way beyond that. Is it reasonable to do something like calling Pipeline.apply or re-creating/running the pipeline repeatedly in a sequential loop without incurring the overhead of starting the workers and doing the support work every time? I was going to play around with it tomorrow, but if there is a proper way, would be helpful to know. Worst case, will probably just allocate the largest machine and execute in the cloud in flat manner.

Comment: Unfortunately no, the Dataflow runner currently can not reuse workers between different pipelines. However, you may have better luck running the same Beam pipeline (identical code) using the Spark runner, against a Spark cluster on Cloud Dataproc. See https://github.com/apache/incubator-beam/tree/master/runners/spark for instructions.